# How and where to define pre-processor directives such that they are accessible wherever we want in the project?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

The intention here is that when the program starts, a particular function will read a configuration file and set some `#define`s. In other parts of this project, these preprocessor directives will decide what code to execute and what not.

Example:
A file X contains:
`#define WHAT 0`

A file Y contains:
`#if (WHAT)`
`// Do this`

**How and where should these types of `#define`s be organized so that they are accessible where they should be without creating a mess?**

Comment: #defines are for compilation, not runtime.

Comment: ... so instead you need variables and `if()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The intention here is that when the program starts, a particular
>   function will read a configuration file and set some #defines. In
>   other parts of this project, these preprocessor directives will decide
>   what code to execute and what not.

As the other answer has said, this is not possible as the preprocessor directives like `#define` are consumed by the compilers pre-processors. What your executable binaries actually see is the compiled modified source which remains the same irrespective of every time you run with a different file that you open. Moreover, there is no concept like loading a configuration file and changing the run time as, C++ is a compiled language and not an interpreted.

What actually is possible is to

- load the configuration file (preferable in a stand format)
- Parse it with publicly available libraries for standard format or write your own parser.
- Use STL objects like map to create a mapping between the configuration key and value
- Place the STL in some namespace so as not to pollute the global namespace and make it extern. Ensure that an extern declaration is present in a header file and the variable is defined in a .cpp file so that the variable can be accesses from a translation unit different from where it was defined.
- Consume the mapped configuration anywhere within your program.

Comment: Thankful to you. Could you please explain this with an example - `Place the STL in some namespace so as not to pollute the global namespace and make it static extern`.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius: Placing a variable in a namespace would minimize  the nightmare of defining variables global. Making a variable extern (sorry the static was a typo) would ensure you can access the variable from all your cpp programs.

Answer (score 3):

Preprocessor directives are resolved when the program is compiled, not when it starts, so what you're asking for can't be done.

You'll need a runtime mechanism to make this work, but that doesn't guarantee code exclusion from the compiled binary.